# Will the Nikon MC-DC2 shutter release cord work with the Nikon D300s?

Tags: nikon, remote, shutter-release, nikon-d300s

I just bought the [Nikon MC-DC2 remote release cord](http://www.nikonusa.com/Nikon-Products/Product/Remote-Cords/25395/MC-DC2-Remote-Cord.html) and when I unpacked it and tried to plug it into my Nikon D300s camera, I found that the camera body actually has no connector input for that kind of connector.

Did I buy the wrong product or am I just doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I believe you purchased the wrong item. The Nikon D300s is compatible with a laundry list of remotes which includes:

- MC-22
- MC-30
- MC-36
- MC-21
- MC-23
- MC-25
- MC-35
- ML-3

Unfortunately the MC-DC2 is compatible with only the following camera bodies:

- D90
- D7000
- D5000
- D3100

Source: [NikonUSA](http://support.nikonusa.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/13803/~/which-remote-can-i-use-with-my-nikon-d-slr?)